# How to handle (i.e Read/Write) private DICOM Tags using DCMTK

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

With respect to handling private tags in DICOM. Could any one give me the coding examples for below :
1. Writing the private tags fixed attribute tag.
2. Similarly examples for reading the private tags.
Note : Some times private tags are getting relocated. How to read the private tags when the private tags gets relocated.
ex: Some times Private Creator will be at 
(4201,0010) LO [Test Data]                        #  16, 1 PrivateCreator
(4201,1000) IS [11]                                     #   2, 1 Unknown Tag & Data

or it can be at 
(4201,0011) LO [Test Data]                        #  16, 1 PrivateCreator
(4201,1100) IS [11]                                     #   2, 1 Unknown Tag & Data

Any suggestions either while reading relocatable private tags. 
Similarly how to avoid relocation while writing.

Answer (score 5):

See example [Dcmtk Wiki How to add private data elements](http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/howto_addprivatedata)

The dcmtk source also includes a private dictionary file (private.dic).
This dictionary can be loaded by an enviroment variable e.g. `DCMDICTPATH=C:\private.dic` or by code

e.g.

```
DcmDataDictionary& dict = dcmDataDict.wrlock();
dict.loadDictionary(dictionaryFilePath);
dcmDataDict.unlock();
```

You should add your private elements to the private dictionary in the correct syntax. Just have a look at the private.dic file, that should help a lot.

e.g. (Group, Private creator Name, element) VR Description VM

```
(0019,"MY PRIVATE CREATOR NAME",1000)   DS  Description 1
```

If your private tags are known by dcmtk, then you can access them as usual.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help in providing the link. I have one more doubt, I donot have control on the incoming DICOM Images where the private tags can be relocatable(as mentioned in the description). In that case also adding the ptivate elements to the private dictionary helps or not?. Will have problem during reading the private tags? Once again Thanks Johnny.

Comment: Yes, it will help, because dcmtk supports this behavior. In case the private creator and depending tags are moved, dcmtk can read it correctly if the tags are specified in the dictionary.

Comment: But DcmItem::findAndGetOFStringArray doesn't find relocated private tag